# How to implement a spam black list check in php?

Tags: php, email

There are a lot of dns have run a centeralized blacklist of spammer, I have a list of them , but how can i connect to them and provide a domin and check whether my ip is in their blacklist? Thank you.

```
Blacklist Check List

access.redhawk.org  b.barracudacentral.org  bl.csma.biz
bl.emailbasura.org  bl.spamcannibal.org bl.spamcop.net
bl.technovision.dk  blackholes.five-ten-sg.com  blackholes.wirehub.net
blacklist.sci.kun.nl    block.dnsbl.sorbs.net   blocked.hilli.dk
cart00ney.surriel.com   cbl.abuseat.org dev.null.dk
dialup.blacklist.jippg.org  dialups.mail-abuse.org  dialups.visi.com
dnsbl.ahbl.org  dnsbl.antispam.or.id    dnsbl.cyberlogic.net
dnsbl.kempt.net dnsbl.njabl.org dnsbl.sorbs.net
dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net  dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net  dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net
duinv.aupads.org    dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net dul.ru
escalations.dnsbl.sorbs.net fl.chickenboner.biz hil.habeas.com
http.dnsbl.sorbs.net    intruders.docs.uu.se    korea.services.net
mail-abuse.blacklist.jippg.org  misc.dnsbl.sorbs.net    msgid.bl.gweep.ca
new.dnsbl.sorbs.net no-more-funn.moensted.dk    old.dnsbl.sorbs.net
pbl.spamhaus.org    proxy.bl.gweep.ca   psbl.surriel.com
pss.spambusters.org.ar  rbl.schulte.org rbl.snark.net
recent.dnsbl.sorbs.net  relays.bl.gweep.ca  relays.bl.kundenserver.de
relays.mail-abuse.org   relays.nether.net   rsbl.aupads.org
sbl.spamhaus.org    smtp.dnsbl.sorbs.net    socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net
spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net    spam.olsentech.net  spamguard.leadmon.net
spamsources.fabel.dk    tor.ahbl.org    web.dnsbl.sorbs.net
whois.rfc-ignorant.org  xbl.spamhaus.org    zen.spamhaus.org
zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net  bl.tiopan.com
```

Is there any way to use php to connect to the list and check my ip?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only used sorbs, but I think the all use the same pattern.

You have to do a DNS query including the reversed IP (ex: 32.45.12.10.socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net), then read the IP. Sorbs will return 127.0.0.X (X being the list it was found in) if a match is found.

So, for a hypothetical IP address like 12.32.145.12:

```
$ip = '12.32.145.12';
$reversedIp = implode('.', array_reverse(explode ('.', $ip)));
$host = $reversedIp.'.socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net';
$response = gethostbyname($host);
```

If your `$response` starts with `127.0.0.` then it is blacklisted by sorbs.

You can iterate through your list and adjust your algorithm for each blacklist service.

Comment: is the sorbs server enough or how many server (the blacklist should be the same, put more server means preventation if the server is broken down?) i should put on it? thanks.

Comment: You can use a few blacklist servers, as a failsafe. But I wouldn't use all of them as it will require your script to perform many DNS requests.

Comment: Why is IP reversed?

Comment: @user147215 - The reversing is a mechanism to allow unauthenticated checks by adding a non trivial level of difficulty to call the service thereby limiting the number of people who spam it with requests. If these services allowed regular order, it would be super easy for any joe/jane to spam the service.